# Joining two multi-dimentional arrays by adding a new dimention in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have two arrays of shape (3,2,3)

```
a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]])
b = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]])
a.shape
b.shape
```

I would like to join these two arrays by adding a new dimention to get (2,3,2,3) like this:

```
c = np.array([[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]], [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]]])
c.shape
```

How would I do this?

Comment: So what's the `a.shape`? `c.shape`? Or do you expect us to count the brackets and deduce that for ourselves?

Comment: Look at `[a,b]`.  Does that look a lot like your `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) (Join a sequence of arrays along a new axis.) on `axis=0` base on concatenate and add a new dimension on the first dimension.

```
c = np.stack((a, b), axis=0)
print(c.shape)
# (2, 3, 2, 3)
```